# Regex find match one word before and after the string encapsulated with {{ }}

Tags: regex, backtracking

example string:

```
Hi,
{{name}} from {{place}}  has closed your leave application (#2473)
```

here regex should match the words next and before curly braces globally.

for example.

> for **{{name}}** it should match **hi** and **from**.
>
> for **{{place}}** it should match **from** and **has**.

Regex I wrote:

`/([^\ ]+?)? +?({{.+?}})[ \n]+([^\ {]+)?/iug`

This is matching correctly if there are more than one word in between two curley braced items. If there is only 1 word it is causing issue.

Currently,

> for **{{name}}** it matches **hi** and **from**. -- this is correclty
>
> for **{{place}}** it matches **has**. -- this is wrong, it should match **from** also

REGEX101 link

> https://regex101.com/r/wtyOIB/1

The original text for sample

```
Hi,

Vinod Sai from hyderabad has closed your leave application (#2473)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enclose the last part into a positive lookahead like this:

```
(?:(\S+)\s+)?({{.*?}})(?=(?:\s+(\S+))?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gRBSdU/2)

**Details**

- `(?:(\S+)\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group that will match  1 or 0 occurrence of 1+ non-whitespace chars (captured into Group 1) and then 1+ whitespace chars
- `({{.*?}})` - Group 2: `{{`, any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=(?:\s+(\S+))?)` - a positive lookahead that will require an optional sequence of 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ non-whitespace chars immediately to the right of the current location while capturing the non-whitespace chars into Group 3, but forcing the regex index to remain where it was before trying to match the lookahead pattern since lookaheads are zero-width assertions.